# Powershell - Store database table in variable

Tags: arrays, database, powershell

I have a powershell script that grabs data from an Access database file. It works good, but the way I'm doing it (by looping through a few hundred employee records), it makes that many queries to the database file. And since this script is running every few minutes, I get a lot of requests to the database. 
To improve the performance and avoid such a number of requests to the database, I was thinking I could technically do only one request per table, and store the entire table in a variable (maybe a hash table or array); and then during the script I can just grab data for each individual employee, without having to make another database query. 
Does anyone know if something like this is possible? Or am I stuck on the option to just make a new connection to the database each loop?

Edit:
Just to clarify: I don't know how to get the table (collection of objects) into a variable like @mjolinor name it in the response: $table[0]. 
This is what I have:
`$objEmergencyMaster = New-Object -comobject ADODB.Recordset`
`$objEmergencyMaster_SQL = "SELECT * FROM [Emergency Master] WHERE [Emergency #] = " + $emergency_nr`
`$objEmergencyMaster.Open($objEmergencyMaster_SQL, $objConnection,$adOpenStatic,$adLockOptimistic)`

After this I do the following to get a single value:
`$group_id = $objEmergencyMaster.Fields.Item("Group ID").Value`

I hope this makes sense
Thank you!

**P.S.** How do I format code here? I tried indenting by four spaces and it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible. If it's just a few hundred records, you could create custom PS objects from the database records and store those either in an array or in a hash table keyed to some unique employee identifier.

The question is how volatile is the data.  If the data gets updated in the DB, your script will not see those changes until it re-reads the DB and rebuilds those objects.

Edit:

Once you have a collection of objects from the database (e.g. $Table[0]), if you want to index them by e.g. EmployeeID:

```
$Employees = @{}
Foreach ($Record in $Table[0])
{ $Employees[$Record.EmployeeID] = $Record }
```

Comment: The data doesn't change that often. Maybe every few hours. Could you provide me an example how could I do the custom PS objects with the unique key? I'm pretty new to PowerShell. Much appreciated.

Comment: Update your question and post your code there so it can get formatted properly.

Comment: Thanks @mjolinor. I think my problem is more basic :). I Updated the question with formatted info (as much as I could)